# Create Order from Backend Shows Product options from another store on page refresh for multisite/store setup

Tags: magento-1.9

1) I have setup of 2 websites (1 for retail and 2 for wholesale) and both has 1 store into it. retail: www.freshforsure.in, wholsale: wholesale.freshforsure.in.

2) Now I have created 1 product named "Dummy" and set website scope as both websites.

3) Next, I have set different Custom Options and Option Values of same product for both websites.

4) Now I am trying to create order from back end using admin credentials under web site wholesale.freshforsure.in by following the steps below.

a) Menu Option Sales -> Orders -> Create New Order
  b) Selected customer from the customer list
  c) Selected wholesale.freshforsure.in

5) Now I have selected and added product named "Dummy" with one of the custom option "30 kg - Rs.300" by clicking "Add Products" button. Selected Item is added to grid with correct options [See screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RW5Z.png)

6) Now on refreshing the page manually or by adding more items, system is replacing wrong Product option (It is picking product option of another website/store) under grid for Item "Dummy" See screenshot after refresh
[refer screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1kL3.png)

Please help.